# In Silverlight, how can I make a new pane appear when a button is pushed?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

On my main window, I have several different buttons and fields that are already working. They are basically a calculator that hides the calculations from the user.

However, I would like to add a button that says "How does it work?" and which slides a new pane in from the side when pressed.

I am doing this on the Windows Phone 7 emulator, but I am using Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to home brew this it would be fairly trivial.  I would just use the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(VS.95).aspx).  Have 2 states for your "How does it work" pane.

1. HowDoIWork_Visible
2. HowDoIWork_Hidden

To accomplish the sliding effect you'll need to have the position the pane off the screen.  So I would add a TranslateTransform to the RenderTransform property of the pane.  Its "X" attribute set would originally be set to the negative width of your pane.  For more info see [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx):

For the **HowDoIWork_Visible** state set the X property of the TranslateTransform to 0. and the Visibility to "Visible" or the Opacity to "1.0".

Now create the **HowDoIWork_Hidden** state so you can once again hide the pane.  Set the pane's Visibility to "Collapsed" or its Opacity to "0.0".  Also set the X property of the TranslateTransform back to the Width.

When the user clicks the Button you just need to call:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState("HowDoIWork_Visible");
```

To hide the pane again:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState("HowDoIWork_Hidden");
```

Other ideas...

You may also be able to adapt the Silverlight Toolkit's Accordion to do what you want:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Control%20Overview%20Pg1&referringTitle=Home

If you're not stuck on the sliding in effect the ChildWindow provides an easy way to open up a dialog type view.
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/29/silverlight-3-s-new-child-windows.aspx

Comment: Is there a way I could use different pages?

Comment: What do you mean by different pages?

If you create the "HowDoIWork" UI as a Silverlight "UserControl" instead of a Page you can add it to the MainPage as you would any other control.  Just make sure to include your namespace at top.

Here's a link with an example:
http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=130